# date picker not appearing

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, mootools

I am trying to display a date picker in 2nd green color but date-picker is n't appearing, but in 1st green color it is coming fine. What should i modify? In fiddle first date is coming fine but when i am clicking green colour of 2nd text box and nothing appears. What type of modification does it require?

Here is the fiddle

http://jsbin.com/unosar/8/edit#javascript,html,live

Any solution please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using same ids for 2 div, either change that to class or use unique ids, like

```
#invokeDP {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: green;
 display: inline-block;    
}
  #invokeDP2 {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: green;
 display: inline-block;    
}

var dp = new DatePicker('.picker', {
  pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
  allowEmpty: true,
    toggleElements: ['invokeDP', 'invokeDP2'] //2 divs with 2 unique ids
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is invalid: you cannot use twice an `id`, the `id` attribute [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id).

It's enough to make it into a class and all will work (see http://jsbin.com/unosar/19/edit#javascript,html,live)

Also, toggle_class can be a simple string, not only an array: http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker#examples

By the way, you should use the official improved [mootools datepicker](https://github.com/arian/mootools-datepicker/) instead.

Comment: @saroj I think it's easier with a single class rather then duplicating things with multiple IDs actually ;-), but pick the solution you prefer as long as it works!

Comment: ya i got it..i just need solution to this problem,any solution please,i have given your example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428513/date-picker-not-appearing-when-cursor-is-put-in-textbox