# date picker not appearing when cursor is put in textbox

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, mootools

I have two date pickers appearing when `green color` is clicked, but when i am putting mouse cursor on those two text boxes, then nothing appears, only after clicking `image/green color` date picker is appearing. What modification should i do?

In this below fiddle automatically date picker is appearing when cursor is put:

http://jsfiddle.net/cBwEK/

I want to add the above function in below fiddle:

http://jsbin.com/unosar/19/edit#javascript,html,live

I am trying but nothing happens. Any solution please

**EDIT: BOTH THESE ABOVE EXAMPLES USE SAME css/js/mootools SCRIPTS**

Comment: @Gavriel is right, but the datepicker you are using is slightly buggy and definitely outdated (3 years old). Use http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the two examples are different. Try to set up an example that is more like your real code. Try to do the same thing in the 2nd example:

```
new DatePicker('.picker', {
     pickerClass: 'picker ',
    allowEmpty: true
});
```

​

Comment: I know, I tried it too, that's why I told you to make 2 identical examples, 'cause it's hard to do anything like this

Comment: here it is: http://jsbin.com/uzagil/edit#javascript,html,live but i am facing a problem that i have given comment in Codrin's answer, any solution please

Comment: that's because you think you have first and second, but looking into your code you see that the two are identical: same id, same class, etc. How do you think datepicker should guess which green div belongs to which input field?

Comment: ya that's the solution i need, any idea please

Comment: @saroj The initial Gavriel solution is correct, it's the datapicker you are using that is a bit buggy (if you click on one input, then click somewhere else, then click on the other input it works; instead clicking from one input to the other does not work as expected). His latest solution works, but I strongly suggest you switch to the official [mootools datepicker](http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootools_datepicker)

Comment: thanks Gavirel for your useful answer, but when clicking on green color, it is n't turning a hand like symbol, can it be like a hand like symbol?

Comment: @Stefano thanks a lot for your useful solution, i will include the latest library?

Comment: @saroj that was not in the original question, but you can just add "cursor:pointer;" to the css class of .invokeDP and it'll add the hand

Answer (score 0):

Add an `click` event on the textboxes:

```
$$('.date').addEvent('click', function() { 
      dp.show(); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i found that when i clicked 2nd green color, then choosed date from date picker and entered the date in 2nd text box, now when i put my cursor on 1st text box then datepicker appeared but when i choosed date , date is entered into 2nd text box, instead of going to 1st text box. Please check it once